# Angular Data received as object

Tags: angular

I am passing data from one component to another but on receiving end I am getting data in object format Here it is as shown I just need those number as output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIR1S.png)

Here is the code which I had written

Component1.ts:-(Here I am navigating to component2):-

```
    this.router.navigate(['/operation', { questions:JSON.stringify(this.que), 
   answers:JSON.stringify(this.answers), level:this.level, operation:this.operation } ]);
```

Component2.ts:- (This component receives)

```
answer = [];
que = [];
level=1
operation=1

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.que = JSON.parse(params.get("questions"))
    this.answer = JSON.parse(params.get("answers"))
    this.level = parseInt(params.get("level"))
    this.operation = parseInt(params.get("operation"))  

  });
```

}

Component2.html: (Here I am displaying)

```
 <div *ngIf="operation === 1"> 
   <div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">{{ i }}.) &nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>
        <div *ngFor="let items of que| keyvalue">
          <div *ngFor="let item of items| keyvalue"> 
              {{ item.value | json }}
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <h4 class="card-title text-center">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   {{ answer }}
   </h4>
</div>
```

How can I acheive the number only result

Comment: how else are you planning to receive your data ?

Comment: I just need those number values of firstNum and secondNum